# How can get http response in javascript function after it is returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, google-visualization, express-handlebars

I need to call a function passing response rendered to a express-handlebars page. How can I do this?

This my controller and it is rendering result to a handlebars page.

```
    return servico.obterMetricasStatusCode()
    .then((resultado) => {
        res.status(200).render('erros', {
            resultado: resultado
        })
    });
```

At handlebars file I have a div with id "chart_div" where I need to put a google chart so I need to call a function that execute this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(resultado);
```

where the variable called "resultado" is the data to generate the chart
but resultado is always undefined when this line is executed.

If I put {{resultado}} inside div the object is printed in screen correctly.

Can I help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to render the returned data, that is accomplished in the view, using your engine. if you are just wanting the data returned so that you can manipulate it, I think you want to use `res.json(resultado)` or `res.send(resultado)`

Comment: Thanks Jay Hamilton! I need to send result to manipulate it in front end function but I need to render to the page too.